# Remove source from software updater

Tags: apt, updates

Some weeks ago I installed the owncloud client on my Ubuntu system. However, it does not seem to be safe and I want to remove it. I deleted it and apparently it is gone. Unfortunately there is still an persistent entry  in the software update. Each time I want to update my system an error aborts everything, because I did not import the public key:

```
sudo apt-get update
...
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223
```

I just could import the public key and no error message would annoy me any longer. But I don't want to trust this key, but simply remove everything concerning owncloud.

I've opened `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I cannot find `http://download.opensuse.org`. Why? Where does `apt-get` get his source list? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you use the `add-apt-repository` command to add the repository?

Comment: Did you check the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`???

Comment: No, I didn't. In fact there are files that  seem to belong to owncloud. What is this folder about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used the `add-apt-repository` command, or its alias `apt-add-repository`, the PPA or source repository can be found in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

It can be removed correctly using:

```
add-apt-repository -r http://download.opensuse.org
```

I'm not aware of any bad effects from just deleting it from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, but I can't say for certain that there will not be any.

Comment: You can just delete the files. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Unity dash and search for `Software Sources`

   [image]
2. Go to Other Software and select the desired PPA to be removed.
3. Click Remove

   [image]